# Go to silent/vibration mode while listening to music

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, volume-control

How can I listen to music and go to silent/vibration mode without having to stop the music? On older versions of Android you just pushed and held the power button and you got a range of alternatives to choose from, but now in Lollipop you only get power off restart etc. No volume options directly. Is there a fix for this?